# Saving values in a class

Tags: c#, class, set

I need to write a program to sort an array. But the initial data was saved in a separate class that I named "Mas1".

```
class Mas1
{
    private int[] m1; // Field that contains the array

    public Mas1(int n) // Class constructor
    {
        if (n > 1)
            m1 = new int[n];
        else
            throw new Exception("Array size must be more than 1");
    } // If the array size is correct, then create the array, else generate an exception

    public int this[int Index1] // Indexer for access to the array elements
    {
        get
        {
            if (Index1 >= 0 && Index1 < m1.GetLength(0))
                return m1[Index1];
            else
                throw new Exception("Index value is incorrect");
        }
        set
        {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

I guess just rewriting lines from get is not correct...

How can I save values in a set?

Comment: Setters receive the value in a variable called `value`

Comment: this should work; `m1[Index1] = value;`

Comment: likerkaran, that's all, and no long answer? I mean, my question is so easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the indexers' set accessor [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/#indexers-overview). It uses an implicit parameter called `value`, whose type is the type of the property. It works just like the usual property accessors in C#.

> **Indexers Overview**
>
> - Indexers enable objects to be indexed in a similar
>   manner to arrays.
> - A get accessor returns a value. A set accessor assigns a value.
> - The this keyword is used to define the indexer.
> - **The *value* keyword is used to define the value being assigned by the
>   *set* accessor.**
> - Indexers do not have to be indexed by an integer value; it is up to
>   you how to define the specific look-up mechanism.
> - Indexers can be overloaded.
> - Indexers can have more than one formal parameter, for example, when
>   accessing a two-dimensional array.

An example for your case would be:

```
set
{
    m1[Index1] = value;
}
```